# powerconnect 2848 telnet commands

Tags: telnet, dell-powerconnect

I would like to find out which IP addresses are on which ports, or when I disconnect a cable to show me which port just dropped? Anyone out there who can shed some light on the telnet commands available or perhaps a cheat sheet of sorts?

Answer (score 1):

[The Dell PowerConnect 2848 user manual contains a section on using the CLI](ftp://ftp.dell.com/Manuals/all-products/esuprt_ser_stor_net/esuprt_powerconnect/powerconnect-2848_user%27s%20guide_en-us.pdf), including commands and examples.  Starts at page 157.  (And took seconds to locate through Google and/or support.dell.com, for future reference.)